# get data from script tag in json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, waze

I am using Waze I frame.
when I embed the iframe in my page I get a script tag like this

```
<script id="i18n-strings" type="text/JSON">
```

just to make things clear the script is created inside the iframe element 
how can I access the data of this script tag?

Comment: If iframe source is from a different origin than the main page ..... you can't access anything inside it

Comment: thank you very much to make it clear for me :)